springboot service actuator api not accessible when deployed in pod in kubernetes
I have a springboot microservice which runs correctly when I run the jar locally and inside docker.
means I am able to access my rest endpoints along with actuator endpoints.
i.e.  http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
however when I am deploying the same in kubernetes using docker desktop, I am not able to connect to my endpoints. not even actuator endpoints are reaching.
when I debugged, the request is not even reaching the service endpoints.
below is my deployment.yml file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '3'
  name: com-etl-my-deployment3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: com-etl-my
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: com-etl-my
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: com-etl-my
        image: etl-my:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: '0.5'
            memory: 0.5Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        env:
        - name: server.port
          value: '8080'
        - name: logging.level.root
          value: INFO
        - name: management.endpoints.web.exposure.include
          value: "*"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: com-etl-my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: com-etl-my

Kindly suggest something so I am able to connect with the endpoints in the service.
thanks and regards

Maybe firewall, you did't specify where are you trying to access the pod from, assuming the app is running and the logs look good, try exec into the container and do the curl request from inside the container.

@Shmuel I am trying to connect to pod from same system. kubernetes is on my local system and pod is inside kubernetes. I am trying to connect from postman on my local system using localhost:8080
